# How to parse a huge file with csv data and calculate average on one of its column in plain Scala?

Tags: scala

I am trying to read a huge file (data in comma seperated values)
The input file contains millions of rows in the below format. The file is also close to 8GB.
Ex:

```
1, 22, Begin, session1
1, 33, End, session1
2, 20, Begin, session1
2, 30, End, session1
1, 30, Begin, session2
1, 50, End, session2
3, 90, Begin, session1
4, 10, Begin, session1
3, 100, End, session1
4, 20, End, session1
3, 200, OPEN, session2
```

The first value is the `RECORDID`, second value is its `WEIGHT`, the third value is the `TRANSACTION_STATUS`, fourth value is `SESSIONID`.
I have to calculate the average of all `WEIGHT` of each `RECORDID` for all of its sessions between its `BEGIN` & `END`.
If there is a session id without `END`, it should be ignored.

Example Output:

```
RECORD ID => 1, WEIGHTS => (33-22) = 11, (50-30)=20 => Average 15.5 
RECORD ID => 2, WEIGHTS => (30-20) = 10 => Average 10.0
RECORD ID => 3, WEIGHTS => (100-90) = 10 => Average 10.0
RECORD ID => 4, WEIGHTS => (20-10) = 10 => Average 10.0
```

Final output:

```
1, 15.5
2, 10.0
3, 10.0
4, 10.0
```

I started to code like below:

```
case class Users(recordid: Int, weight: Int, transaction_status: String, sessionid: String)
val userList = List[Users]()
val in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("/Users/Desktop/sessionfile.txt")))
Iterator continually in.readLine takeWhile (_ != null) foreach(println)
```

As my input file is a big file, I used InputStreamReader & Iterator to read records from the file. But I am a bit confused here because I previously did the above activity on a Spark Dataset where I created objects of my case class to represent the dataset with type Users => Dataset[Users] and Dataframe with spark SQL
In this case, the code should only be written in plain Scala without using any implementation of Spark or SQL.

Could anyone let me know what is the efficient way to achieve the solution in plain scala code ? Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to go about it.

```
val beginRE = raw"\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*Begin.*".r
val endRE   = raw"\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*End.*".r

util.Using(io.Source.fromFile("./inFile.csv")){
  _.getLines().foldLeft(Map[String,(Long,Int,Int)]()){
    case (acc, beginRE(recID, wght)) =>  //Begin record
      val (rt, cnt, _) = acc.getOrElse(recID,(0L,0,0))
      acc + (recID -> (rt, cnt, wght.toInt))
    case (acc, endRE(recID, wght)) =>    //End record
      val (rt, cnt, bgn) = acc.getOrElse(recID,(0L,0,-1))
      if (bgn < 0) {
        println(s"orphan End record: '$recID,$wght,...'")
        acc
      } else
        acc + (recID -> (rt + wght.toInt - bgn, cnt+1, -1))
    case (acc, rec) =>                   //bad record
      println(s"bad record: $rec")
      acc
  }
}.map(_.map{case (k,(rt,cnt,_)) => k -> rt/cnt.toDouble})
//res0: Try[Map[String,Double]] =
//    Success(Map(1 -> 15.5, 2 -> 10.0, 3 -> 10.0, 4 -> 10.0))
```

If there are multiple `Begin` records only the last one counts. The rest are ignored.

If there are multiple `End` records only the first one counts. The rest are reported as "orphaned."

Comment: I upvoted this solution as it is working. Just want to understand one more thing. My input file is close to 8GB & there is a chance of memory issues. Can you please let me know if this is an efficient way to work on a huge files like in this scenario ?

Comment: Fore example, in my trial code I gave in the question, I used an Iterator and all the transformations are lazy until the `foreach` condition.

Comment: `getLines()` returns an `Iterator[String]`. The `foldLeft()` consumes the iterator 1 line of text (from the file) at a time. A new key->value entry is added to the resulting `Map` only when a new record ID is encountered. This should be memory efficient unless you have a huge number of unique record IDs.